# This keyword in ReactJs and why we loose the context

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
class Foo extends React.Component{
  constructor( props ){
    super( props );
  }
 
  handleClick(event){
    console.log(this); // 'this' is undefined
  }
 
  render(){
    return (
      <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
        Click Me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <Foo />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

I've red about this keyword, but i can't understand why in this case when i click on the button `this` is undefined? In this case `this` should point to the class `Foo` , why it is `windows object`? How the context is lost in this case?

Comment: Looks like react is binding the `window` object on onClick and check it what you get if you explicitly bind `this.handleClick.bind(this)`

Answer (score 0):

```
handleClick = (event)=>{
    console.log(this); //
  }
```

> This is due to context use `arrow function`

handleClick is call in the context of click event of button, due to this refers to window context in handleClick, but when you use arrow function it will solve the issue

Comment: I've red about this keyword, but i can't understand why in this case when i click on the button this is undefined? In this case this should point to the class Foo , why it is windows object? How the context is lost in this case?

Comment: because onClick callback is called in the global context and global context is window in this case.

Comment: this rule is valid for all methods inside classes? we should bind all methods inside class components?

Comment: we should bind all methods inside class components? - NO  - only when current execution context change means in your case - the handleClick function is called in the context of onClick

Comment: When the code is called from an inline on-event handler, its this is set to the DOM element on which the listener is placed,  now in onClick the inner function's this isn't set so it returns the global/window object (i.e. the default object in non–strict mode where this isn't set by the call).